# How Insecure is OS X Lion (10.7.5)?

Tags: macos, windows, security, upgrade, unix

I've got an older (classic?) black plastic MacBook that can't be upgraded past OS X Lion (10.7.5). It looks like it's no longer receiving security updates, and critical software (like web browsers) have also discontinued support. This makes me nervous to use it on today's internet. Should I install something like Windows 10 or Linux Mint instead? (If it weren't for security issues I'd be fine keeping it running as-is.)

Comment: Hmm I would be suprised if you could get windows 10 running but I don't have experience with your model.

Comment: Just got Windows 10 installed. Updating and installing Office now to test. Trackpad gestures not working, for one thing.

Comment: Let me know if the external monitor works.  Would be suprised but it might.

Comment: You will find no drivers for a lot of the hardware - some generic features may still work, but nothing very specific. btw, the last security update for 10.7.5 was in 2014, so you are I suppose wise to no longer use it. on the contra, OSX has never presented its flanks to the average 'script kiddie' who goes for the low-hanging fruit, so removing Flash, Silverlight, Java etc might not be a total fail.

Comment: As an update, both Windows 10 and Linux Mint installed and worked, but both had issues with the trackpad and other drivers. I ended up restoring OS X and switched to a long term support version of Firefox that has a few more months of updates. It seems there's no ideal solution for this otherwise usable hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would definitely recommend installing an operating system which is currently supported with security updates. Whether that system is a version of Windows, Linux or something else is entirely up to your likings.

Running an old, non-supported OS X on a machine connected to the Internet is not a good idea, if you have problems with it being compromised.